POST Request data validation using Pydantic and Annotated
I am working with several POST API requests and I have validation schemas for all POST APIs. I am trying to validate whether URL coming from the POST request is valid. I am using Pytest to write tests for all the APIs.
I am trying to validate incoming data like this:
url: Annotated[str, HttpUrl]

I have tried sending it several invalid url, but here is an example of one that would be coming in the json:
"url": "www.bad.example",

For some reason, I simply do not get a validation error using the method above no matter what. I tried consulting ChatGPT as well as Google, however, I have not find answer to this anywhere.
I have tried using both AnyUrl as well as HttpUrl. I have also tried:
url: Annotated[HttpUrl, ...]

It does validate invalid URL but it makes my positive test fail with this error message:
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) Error binding parameter 4: type 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core.Url' is not supported

Therefore, I was hoping to stick with the str type, which does not cause this error, but also does not really validate properly with HttpUrl rules.

You can achieve this by writing a functional validator like so:
from typing import Annotated

from pydantic import BaseModel, HttpUrl, AfterValidator

HttpStr = Annotated[HttpUrl, AfterValidator(str)]


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    url: HttpStr


m1 = MyModel(url="https://hello.com")
assert m1.url == "https://hello.com/"

m2 = MyModel(url="https://hello[.]com")  # raises ValidationError("Input should be a valid URL, invalid domain character")

In this example we leverage HttpUrl annotated type, and then add an AfterValidator to coerce the Url back into a string.
However, quickly shimming through the SQLAlchemy documentation it looks like this might be a common problem with a documented workaround. Potentially this might be more elegant approach to your specific problem?

A frequent need is to force the “string” version of a type, that is the one rendered in a CREATE TABLE statement or other SQL function like CAST, to be changed.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/custom_types.html#overriding-type-compilation
